# Custom internal DNS

Tags: dns, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

According to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/internal-dns) page, every VM instance has a DNS entry of the following form:

**hostName.c.[PROJECT_ID].internal**

This would look something like:

**ownserver.c.myproject.internal**

My question is: can I somehow add a custom internal DNS name for this server, so something like:

**othername.c.myproject.internal**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run your own DNS server and use that; you can't modify the internal DNS records, however.

Comment: How can I achive this?

Comment: If you're familiar with BIND and DNS, this should be straightforward enough.  I'm honestly not, and I can't provide any advice on how to do that.